# How can I keep track of the number of times I submit a form in CakePHP?

Tags: forms, cakephp

I need some idea in Saving the Form entries.

In my app, I have designed the form using Cakephp and JQuery, saved the form and I can view the form.

While I fill the entries in the form it is saved in my `results` table.
My `results` table schema looks like this:  (`id`, `form_id`, `attribute_id`, `label`, `value`)

I can view the form n times and can fill the data n times ...
But I didn't kept anything regarding Entry Number ...

Like if I submitted my form once it should be the Entry 1 ..And later on if I open the form again and fill it it should be the entry 2.
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Would you remove the code formatting tags from your text?  Makes it a bit difficult to read (I know, I'm being lame).

Comment: Also, this is question is rather difficult to answer without seeing actual source code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the numer of times you've revised each row in your table, then simply create a column named revision_number in your table with a default of 0. Then in your model do something like this:

```
function beforeSave() {
  $currentRevision = $this->field('revision_number');
  $this->data[$this->alias]['revision_number'] = ($currentRevision + 1);
  return parent::beforeSave()
}
```

This will increment your field every time you save the item.